# Path of Trash in attributesOfItemAtPath:

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, nsfilemanager, recycle-bin

I am creating a cocoa app which will give the size of the Trash in MB,GB,etc. So far I have got the code to find the size of an item at a given path:

```
 unsigned long long fileSize = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:@"/Users/myusername/Documents" error:nil] fileSize];
 NSLog(@"%lld", fileSize);
```

However, I do not know the path of the current users trash. So if some could tell be the path of the trash which would work in my above code, it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Current user's trash is under `~/.Trash`. Apple does not have an official way of putting files into trash programmatically. You can try checking out [CocoaDev wiki on the topic](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/MoveToTrash).

Comment: Result is 0 when I use '~/.Trash' in the above code, when files are in the trash.

Comment: There is now a `FileManager` function to trash item: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1414306-trashitem